# dynamic memory allocation in C++ without pointers - what's the point of pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, dynamic

Consider the following C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int p_values[], int size, int elements_set);

int main() 
{
    int next_element = 0;
    int size = 3;
    int p_values[size]; 
    int val;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> val;

    while (val > 0)
    {
    if (size == next_element+1)
    {
        size *=2;
        int p_values[size];
    }
    p_values[next_element] = val;
    next_element++;
    cout << "Current array values are: " << endl;
    printArray(p_values, size, next_element);
    cout << "Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): ";
    cin >> val;
    }   

}


void printArray(int p_values[], int size, int elements_set) 
{
cout << "Total size of array: " << size << endl;
cout << "Number of slots set so far: " << elements_set << endl;
cout << "Values in the array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements_set; ++i){
        cout << "p_values[" << i << "] = "
             << p_values[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

What the code does is simply this: 
1. the user is asked for a number
2. the number is saved in an array
3. the current content of the array is printed out

Once the array is full, its size is doubled. 
Such a dynamic increase of an array during runtime is usually done with a pointer.
In fact, I was told that such dynamic increasing of an array size is only possible by using pointers.

However, as you can see in the program above, I did not use any pointers but only a static array. Nevertheless, the program dynamically increases the sizeof the array at runtime.

Therefore, my questions are these:
1. Why was I told at university (and also in several books) that, in a C++ program, increasing memory usage during runtime is only possible by using pointers?
2. What's the point of pointers (apart from making it possible to pass variables by reference when calling a function), given the dynamic memory allocation can be done without them?

After having run the program for a while and having entered 8 numbers, the output of the program looks as follows:

```
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 8
Current array values are: 
Total size of array: 12
Number of slots set so far: 8
Values in the array: 
p_values[0] = 1
p_values[1] = 2
p_values[2] = 3
p_values[3] = 4
p_values[4] = 5
p_values[5] = 6
p_values[6] = 7
p_values[7] = 8
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit):
```

Comment: To be fair, this isn't a C++ program. VLAs are not a part of C++.

Comment: Pointers are for pointing at things. How the things get allocated is a different matter.

Comment: what are VLAs, if I may ask?

Comment: It also doesn't consider scope.  The `p_values` inside the braces is not the same as the `p_values` at the top of main, and accessing it outside of it's original bounds is undefined behavior.  The short answer is "you didn't do it."

Comment: @steady_progress Variable-length arrays: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays

Comment: @krzaq It is a C++ program. The array is static. I'm just repeatedly overwriting it.

Comment: @steady_progress C++ requires arrays to have compile-time-known sizes. Your doesn't, ergo it is not a C++ program. Compilers with non-standard extensions may accept it, but it doesn't make it any more C++.

Comment: @steady_progress You are not overwriting the original array at all, the newly declared array inside the braces is a different variable completely and disappears at the closing brace.

Comment: Not only you are using VLA, you are not increasing the original array dimension at all. You defined a new local array with VLA. You were merely writing into stack pass the boundary of your old array. In either case, sooner or later you will has stack overflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    size *=2;
    int p_values[size];
}
```

Nope. This does not increase the size of the existing `p_values` array, declared at the beginning of the function. This declares a different array named `p_values`, in the inner scope...

...and since the inner scope immediately ends here, this has no effect whatsoever. The loop the continues and runs off the end of the original `p_values` array, resulting in undefined behavior and memory corruption.

> Nevertheless, the program dynamically increases the sizeof the array
>   at runtime.

No, it didn't. The size of the existing array was not dynamically increased. A different, larger variable-length array was declared in inner scope, and immediately destroyed. The original array remained at its original size, and undefined behavior resulted.

Just keep inputting more values into the array, and at some point you'll end up smashing the return address on the stack, resulting in a segfault when `main()` returns (assuming your compiler implements variable-length arrays dynamically by adjusting the size of the current function's stack frame).

Comment: @Varshachik ... so the memory location of the new array is not (!) the memory location of the old array plus some extra memory? Put differently: the first element of the new array is in a completely different memory location than the first value of the old array? ... Furthermore, the memory space that was used by the old array(s) is not freed so my program causes memory leakage?

Comment: No, the two arrays are completely independent objects, that have nothing to do with each other, whatsoever. Additionally, there is no memory leakage. Both the new array and the old array's memory gets released when their respective scope terminates, provided that no undefined behavior occured. Once undefined behavior occurs, the results, by definition, are undefined.

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of fact

```
int size = 3;
int p_values[size];
```

is not valid C++.    This feature (variable length arrays) was introduced into C with the 1999 standard, and is not in any C++ standard, or is it proposed to be added.    Some C++ compilers (and some C compilers predating the 1999 C standard) support this feature as a *non-standard* extension.

Even if we assume a compiler that supports C's VLAs, this

```
int size = 3;
int p_values[size]; 

/* other code */
{
    size *=2;
    int p_values[size];
}
```

does not resize `p_values`.   It temporarily creates another array, within the nested scope (i.e. in the `{}`) that no longer exists outside the scope.

Comment: yes, I have understood that now ... thank you all very much for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work.  Your 'reallocation' doesn't do anything - you're creating another array which shadows the name.  In the mean time, you're overwriting memory that's not yours (e.g. p_values[9] is where the size variable is stored). Keep going, and it becomes more clear:

```
Please enter a number: 1
Current array values are:
Total size of array: 3
Number of slots set so far: 1
Values in the array:
p_values[0] = 1
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 2
Current array values are:
Total size of array: 3
Number of slots set so far: 2
Values in the array:
p_values[0] = 1
p_values[1] = 2
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 3
Current array values are:
Total size of array: 6
Number of slots set so far: 3
Values in the array:
p_values[0] = 1
p_values[1] = 2
p_values[2] = 3
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 4
Current array values are:
Total size of array: 6
Number of slots set so far: 4
Values in the array:
p_values[0] = 1
p_values[1] = 2
p_values[2] = 3
p_values[3] = 4
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 5
Current array values are:
Total size of array: 6
Number of slots set so far: 5
Values in the array:
p_values[0] = 1
p_values[1] = 2
p_values[2] = 3
p_values[3] = 4
p_values[4] = 5
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 6
Current array values are:
Total size of array: 12
Number of slots set so far: 6
Values in the array:
p_values[0] = 1
p_values[1] = 2
p_values[2] = 3
p_values[3] = 4
p_values[4] = 5
p_values[5] = 6
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 7
Current array values are:
Total size of array: 12
Number of slots set so far: 7
Values in the array:
p_values[0] = 1
p_values[1] = 2
p_values[2] = 3
p_values[3] = 4
p_values[4] = 5
p_values[5] = 6
p_values[6] = 7
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 8
Current array values are:
Total size of array: 12
Number of slots set so far: 8
Values in the array:
p_values[0] = 1
p_values[1] = 2
p_values[2] = 3
p_values[3] = 4
p_values[4] = 5
p_values[5] = 6
p_values[6] = 7
p_values[7] = 8
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 9
Current array values are:
Total size of array: 12
Number of slots set so far: 10
Values in the array:
p_values[0] = 1
p_values[1] = 2
p_values[2] = 3
p_values[3] = 4
p_values[4] = 5
p_values[5] = 6
p_values[6] = 7
p_values[7] = 9
p_values[8] = 10
p_values[9] = 12
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 11
Current array values are:
Total size of array: 12
Number of slots set so far: 11
Values in the array:
p_values[0] = 1
p_values[1] = 2
p_values[2] = 3
p_values[3] = 4
p_values[4] = 5
p_values[5] = 6
p_values[6] = 7
p_values[7] = 11
p_values[8] = 11
p_values[9] = 12
p_values[10] = 11
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 12
Current array values are:
Total size of array: 24
Number of slots set so far: 12
Values in the array:
p_values[0] = 1
p_values[1] = 2
p_values[2] = 3
p_values[3] = 4
p_values[4] = 5
p_values[5] = 6
p_values[6] = 7
p_values[7] = 12
p_values[8] = 12
p_values[9] = 24
p_values[10] = 11
p_values[11] = 12
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 13
Current array values are:
Total size of array: 24
Number of slots set so far: 13
Values in the array:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: the newly created array doesn't do anything and gets destroyed after the brackets are left

Answer (score 0):

Nested definition of an identically denoted array, not dynamic re-allocation, proving ineffective to the obvious intent and ultimately producing memory corruption due to the deregulated input.